# AS3 - Check if a callback function meets certain argument criteria?

Tags: actionscript-3, callback

If I set up a function that accepts a callback:

```
function loadSomething(path:String, callback:Function):void;
```

And that callback should accept a given type, for example a String to represent some loaded information:

```
function onLoaded(response:String):void;

// Load some data into onLoaded.
loadSomething("test.php", onLoaded);
```

Is it possible to assess the function that will be used for callback and ensure that it has both a given amount of arguments and that the argument accepts the correct type? e.g.

```
function broken(arg:Sprite):void;

// This should throw an error.
loadSomething("test.php", broken);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should bother doing this kind of check as it would create an uncessary overhead. You can simply throw the exception when you do the callback:

```
try {
    doCallback(response);
} catch(e:*) {
    trace('Incompatible callback');
}
```

If you really want to do the check, you might be able to do it using reflection. Just call `describeType(callback)` from `flash.utils` and parse the XML.

Comment: Describe type doesn't reflect closures functions.

Answer (score -1):

One simple thing you can do is to check the number of acceptable arguments by calling `length` property on method closure like:

```
function some ( val1 : int, val2 : int ) : void { return; }

trace(some.length); // traces 2
```

Other much more complex method maybe is to use [AS3Commons bytecode library](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/). You can experiment with [dynamic proxies](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/proxy.html).

Comment: It looks like AS3Commons bytecode library only works with raw bytecode, and I don't think a script can access its own bytecode at runtime.